# Lync SDK . Issue with Multiple UI threads

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, lync, lync-client-sdk

I'm seeing an issue where having multiple UI threads with Lync 2010 SDK controls are causing the program to crash.

The error I'm running into is:

```
{"Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject."}
```

If someone can give me an explanation as to why this happens ,or how to get around this. It will be great!

```
<Window x:Class="Lync.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:lync="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Lync.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Lync.Controls"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <StackPanel>
            <lync:PresenceIndicator Source="sip:gawicks@home.com"/>
            <Button Height="20" Width="20"  Click="Button_Click"> </Button>        
        </StackPanel>
    </Window>



  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Simply creating another UI thread on button click https://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {

                MainWindow w = new MainWindow();
                //Crash!!
                w.Show();

                w.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
                 w.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

                System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
            });

            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();

        }
```

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with LYNC, rather it's an issue with attempting to spin up a new GUI on some thread other than the thread the current window is running.  Get rid of your Thread logic and you'll be ok.

Comment: The requirement IS to run on a new thread. Which should work https://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/. All other controls work fine. I can confirm that the lync control is causing the problem.

Comment: Try setting thread.IsBackground = true after setting the ApartmentState

Comment: Ok. One other thing you can try is setting the SynchronizationContext (in the thread start, before the main window initialization) like so: `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
        new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));`

Comment: The Lync client SDK is kind of garbage.  It has some serious issues with threading.  It'd be nice if Microsoft would ever get around to an update - but as it is, it is easier to build your own UI elements that interact with a decently multi-threaded UCMA or UCWA backend if that is at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is indeed a limitation of the Lync controls. Internally these controls use the Lync client. And the lync client being a COM wrapper likes to live on a single UI thread.

So instead I came up with my own control. Wrote a facade over the lync client which lives on a single UI thread. And Dispatched all calls to it. And Voilà its working!

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Simply creating another UI thread on button click https://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
            new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

            MainWindow w = new MainWindow();
            //Crash!!
            w.Show();

            w.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
            w.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();

    }
```

Try setting the SynchronizationContext of the newly created thread as shown above.

Comment: What is happening in the constructor for `MainWindow`? If you strip it down to `InitializeComponent` does it still throw the error?

Comment: Yes ive got zero logic in there except InitializeComponent().

Comment: And just out of curiosity if you remove this line from the xaml `<lync:PresenceIndicator Source="sip:gawicks@home.com"/>` does it still throw the error?. If it doesn't then it does indeed look like it's to do with LYNC

Comment: edit : sorry I meant that the error goes away if <lync:PresenceIndicator Source="sip:gawicks@home.com"/> is removed. So I'm fairly confident this is lync specific.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions given here will work if Lync itself dissallows more than a singleton instance of Lync.  If I recall, this is the case as the designers wanted it that way.  Lync simply will not start twice.

Comment: yes Im aware. There are several equivalent approaches to creating a WPF UI thread . The question is rather , why the lync sdk behaves erratically in this situation.

Comment: Ok, but the code above doesn't show the starting of the dispatcher on the new thread, per Reed's article.  Can you try that?

Comment: Maybe we were misunderstanding the issue a bit, does the exception happen in the button click logic or when the mainwindow is shown prior to the button click?

Comment: The button click logic fires off a new UI thread. It's here that the exception happens.